# plot a data.frame without interpolating

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

Imagine that you have the following data.frame (where there are consecutive numbers that do not appear, in this case time= 4, 7, and 8) and you want to graph haz vs time.
You obtain this plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
time <- c(0,1,2,3,5,6,9,10)
haz<- c(0.05, 0.15, 0, 0.20, 0.25, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30)
df<- data.frame(time, haz)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, haz))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 0, to=10, by = 1))
```

[image]

However, due to the characteristics of the variables, when these numbers do not appear, the graph in Y (haz) should be 0, and give rise to the following graph.

[image]

Which I get with the code

```
time <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
haz<- c(0.05, 0.15, 0, 0.20, 0, 0.25, 0.10, 0, 0, 0.20, 0.30)
df<- data.frame(time, haz)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_step(aes(time, haz))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 0, to=10, by = 1))
```

How to do the process automatically, without manually modifying the data.frame in case it is very long??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use `tidyr::complete` to fill up your dataframe.

```r
library(ggplot2)
time <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10)
haz <- c(0.05, 0.15, 0, 0.20, 0.25, 0.10, 0.20, 0.30)
df <- data.frame(time, haz)
df <- tidyr::complete(df, time = 0:10, fill = list(haz = 0))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_step(aes(time, haz)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 1))
```

[image]